# Local domain file in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos-7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLedr.png)I'm trying to set up a local domain server on CentOS 7, Here is my configuration file. I keep getting a syntax error near Serial and I can't figure out why.

```
;
;Data file for nightstalker.local
;
$TTL 2D
nightstalker.local.     IN SOA nightstalker.local. root.nightstalker.local. (
                        20191130      ; Serial 
                        1D            ; Refresh
                        2H            ; Retry
                        1W            ; Expire
                        2D )          ; Default TTL

        IN NS phantomlord.nightstalker.local. 
;       IN MX

phantomlord     IN A    192.168.0.8
;
;
;
;
;
```

and here is the error I'm getting.

```
named-checkzone NightStalker.local. named.NightStalker.local.zone.
dns_rdata_fromtext: named.NightStalker.local.zone.:6: near 'Serial': syntax error
zone NightStalker.local/IN: loading from master file named.NightStalker.local.zone. failed: syntax error
zone NightStalker.local/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

I created this file from scratch but I have also gone as far as to go online and copy a supposedly good config file and paste it in and added my information and still got the exact same error even after a reboot. Can someone explain to me what's going on or what I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to this so at this point I'm grasping at straws.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking this exact file?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is the right file, I added two screenshots the first one is the file I made and I'm using on the server for the local domain and the second is the actual error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Line 10 of you file should have the right parenthesis after the comment or better on the next line by itself.